# How to set third-party cookies with Flutter app

Tags: flutter, cookies

I am building an app, which shows users a lot of offers, when user clicks an offer, I want to store some cookies in his browser.

1. When user clicks the offer, I am opening a WebView in Flutter with the help of [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package.
2. Now how should I store cookies on a domain of the offer. For example, the offer is from Myntra, I want to store a cookie on Myntras website.

Is this possible in Flutter? If yes, how?